# How to force logout of user in owncloud?

Tags: owncloud

Let's say your computer which is logged in to your owncloud instance gets stolen and you want to force-logout yourself remotely. Even if you change your password, the logins stay active.

I can see that you can do that from the interface in the enterprise edition (see image) but I cannot find a way to do it in the community edition.

[image: force-logout-owncloud]

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the database, find and delete the `login_token` that corresponds to your username in the table `oc_preferences`. After that, you must clear the php session files (in my case, Ubuntu 14.04 located at `/var/lib/php5`)

You will see that all your sessions will be immediately terminated.